# Getting unknown column in on clause when trying to get the latest record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables `orders` and `order_items` I am trying to get the last `order_sum` for each day using an inner join but I am running into an error in my second join.

> Unknown column 'o.last_order_date' in 'on clause

Here is my query

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    sum(o.order_sum) as total_order_sum,
    sum(i.total_energy_used) as total_energy_used,
    max(o.created_at) as last_order_date,
    o2.order_sum as last_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select order_id, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
    from order_items i
    group by order_id
) i on o.id = i.order_id
inner join (
  select created_at, order_sum from orders
) o2 on o2.created_at = o.last_order_date
group by date(o.created_at)
```

And here is the result I would like to get

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| date_of_month | total_order_sum | total_energy_used | last_order_date     | last_order_sum |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2020-01-25    | 35.13           | 164               | 2020-01-25 15:23:00 | 10.00          |
| 2020-01-26    | 64.00           | 1                 | 2020-01-26 19:14:00 | 50.00          |
| 2020-01-27    | 35.00           | 5                 | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 | 35.00          |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Here is a fiddle with schema
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf799d/6

Comment: I'm a bit confused; I feel like we've covered this already, but great that you've provided a fiddle

Comment: @Strawberry I am learning. We did get everything except for the last ````order_sum```` for each day. That I still can't get for some reason...

Comment: Does orders table have a last_order_date column?

Comment: @jarlh no as you can see in the fiddle the last_order_date is a derived column from an inner join

Comment: I see. Those are only available in the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already asked this in your previous question you were nearly there with the second inner join

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum,
    sum(i.total_energy_used) total_energy_used,
    max(o.created_at) lastorderdate,
    max(s.last_order_sum) last_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select order_id, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
    from order_items i
    group by order_id
) i on o.id = i.order_id
join
(select order_sum last_order_sum,created_at
    from orders o
    where created_at = (select max(created_at) from orders o1 where date(o1.created_at) = date(o.created_at))
) s on date(s.created_at) = date(o.created_at) 
group by date(o.created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

the aggregated column cannot yet be used in the join condition.
you can try to do it with a subselect

```
select t.* 
,o2.order_sum as last_order_sum
from (
    select 
        date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
        sum(o.order_sum) as total_order_sum,
        sum(i.total_energy_used) as total_energy_used,
        max(o.created_at) as last_order_date

    from orders o
    inner join (
        select order_id, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
        from order_items i
        group by order_id
    ) i on o.id = i.order_id
     group by date(o.created_at) 
) t
inner join (
  select created_at, order_sum from orders
) o2 on o2.created_at =t.last_order_date
```

**Result:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf799d/16

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated sub-query here :

```
select date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
       sum(o.order_sum) as total_order_sum,
       sum(i.total_energy_used) as total_energy_used,
       max(o.created_at) as last_order_date,
       (select o1.order_sum 
        from orders o1 where date(o.created_at) = date(o1.created_at)
        order by o1.created_at desc
        limit 1
       ) as last_order_sum    
from orders o inner join 
     (select order_id, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
      from order_items i
      group by order_id
     ) i 
     on o.id = i.order_id
group by date(o.created_at);
```

Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf799d/19) demo.